# "App not installed" after switching Android app's main Activity to other name

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In the `AndroidManifest` file of my application, the main `Activity`'s `android:name` has always been:

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Recently, I have changed the app to use a library. All the code has been transferred to the library project so that I can offer a free and a paid version, both using the same code (except to some modifications).

Now the name of the main `Activity` in the manifest file is:

```
android:name="com.name.library.MainActivity"
```

Unfortunately, users are reporting now that they cannot open the updated app anymore on their phone. Android says: `App not installed!`

After some searching, I [found the cause for this problem here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html): You cannot change an `Activity`'s name without causing problems for other apps trying to use `Intent`s for this app. I guess the users who report the problem have placed my app on their home screen and the launcher application doesn't find the old `Activity` name anymore. Is that true?

But does this also affect the menu with all apps listed? Actually, Android should update the `Activity`'s name on update, shouldn't it?

And how to resolve this problem? My only idea is to create a new `Activity` with the old name and in `onCreate(...)`, place the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.setComponentName("com.app.library", "com.app.library.MainActivity);
startActivity(i);
```

But this is not a pleasant solution, obviously ...

Comment: Perhaps you should not put the actual activities in the library - it seems like poor organization even if it were working.  But you might however be able to keep the bulk of their implementation there, for example by have custom activity types in the library, and then having each application version just have classes which are little more than instances of those.

Comment: Why is that poor organization? If the MainActivity is the same for both free and paid version, why shouldn't I just place this `Activity` in the library project and reference it from both actual projects? Do you think I should make the library's MainActivity abstract and implement them them in both projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could also use an activity-alias .

```
<activity-alias
        android:targetActivity="com.name.library.MainActivity"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/label"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

android:name should match the old activity name

Comment: Remove the filter and add the attribute `android:exported="true"` to the `activity-alias` - then it works perfectly! Exactly the kind of solution I was searching for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

i think you have made your changes in a wrong way. You don't have so many choises: since the moment the user puts a shortcut to your app on his homescreen, the shorcut refers to a specific  uri (you.old.package.MainActivity) and i think the only thing you can do is what you said, even if is not a pleasant solution.  The other solution is that the users delete and recreate the shortcut to your app, since the moment that when an application changes it-s internal structure, the intent which is launched is always the one with the intent filters

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

declared in the manifest; so re-creating the shortcut will fix the problem.

You should have made the changes in order to let the old project to become the library project, and create the Lite and Pro projects to use the original project became a libray project. 
In this way the uri of your activity did not need to be changed

Comment: Thank you! The hint in the last paragraph is good, but I didn't know before updating my app. So now I have to deal with the problem. Next time I'll do what you suggested. One last question: The homescreen icon uses a fixed `Uri` while the icons in the launcher menu are always up-to-date, is that correct? So now problems starting the app from the list of all apps, right?

Comment: sorry but I'm not understanding the question, what do you mean for "So now problems starting the app from the list of all apps" ? in any case when you update the app icon, the icon is updated in the homescreen as well (i don't know what happens when the newly installed app has the main activity's uri changed, but usually if you change the application icon and you have a shortcut on the home screen, the shortcut icon is updates)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say: "So there are no problems starting the app from the list of all apps, right?" The thing that I don't understand is: The `Uri` for the homescreen icon doesn't seem to be updated. But you have the list of all installed apps (the phone's menu) and there the `Uri` is always updated, isn't it?

Comment: yes, in the app drawer (the phone's menu as you call it) the uri is always updated and you can always launch the app from there. please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied